# Steam won't launch 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, games, steam

I tried to install Steam from Software center and ,the apt and the Flatpak method.
First time run and I can login. However, after reboot it is not working.
Ubuntu 22.04 is fresh install. Everything besides Steam working without any issues. Thanks for the help.

Terminal: steam

steam.sh[6174]: Running Steam on Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit

steam.sh[6174]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically

setup.sh[6310]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[6174]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Wayland session fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try as Root in `/usr/share/applications/steam.desktop` change value `PrefersNonDefaultGPU` from `true` to `false`.
Reboot

Comment: I do not have this path.

Comment: Maybe it's in a different directory for you. Try to find with `locate`.
`sudo apt install locate`
`sudo updatedb`
`locate -i steam.desktop`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I created startup desktop icon with `PrefersNonDefaultGPU=false` and it works like a charm.